# How to get nested path of all empty windows directory using cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have a folder and numerous nested folders are present inside that. Many of the folders are empty and I have to copy an empty.property file in those empty folders. So that the end result will be no folder will be completely empty, either it contains another folder, any other file(s) or this empty.property. I have tried to get all the paths using dir /b /s, but it is returning all the paths, not only the empty one. Can anyone help me to get that very efficiently. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use powershell to do it several ways with one being:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Directory | Where-Object {$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0} | 
    ForEach-Object -Process { Copy-Item -Path "My\File\to\copy\Path" -Destination $_.FullName }
```

Basically checks to see which directory doesnt have no files or folders in it, then pipes it to a foreach to a process a `Copy-Item` request for whatever file/folder you want it to copy from, to the empty folder.